# Get variable from string

Tags: javascript

'Im trying to extract multiple variables from a string.

The string `"var context = [{data: 'some data'}]; /* Some garbage comment blabla */ var foo = 3;"` my code will only look for the variables `context` and `foo`.

```
var stringToEval = "var context = [{data: 'some data'}];/* Some garbage  comment blabla */ var foo = 3;";

function evalString() {
    eval(stringToEval);

    if (context !== null && context !== undefined) {
        // Do something
    }

    if (foo !== null && foo !== undefined) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

My solution uses `eval()` but since I don't have control of the input this is a security issue.

Is there a way around eval()? or how can I prevent the execution of functions inside eval?

Comment: You should use sanitizer or regex

Comment: i write some code with regex, you cand try based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

I write some code to do this, based on your string pattern, maybe it refer to you needed:

Working Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/aw6j9upL/6/

Code:

```js
const stringToEval = "var context = [{data: 'some data'}];/* Some garbage  comment blabla */ var foo = 3;";

const contextBadJson = stringToEval.replace(/(.*)(var context = \[)(.*)(\];)(.*)/mg, '[$3]');


const fixBadJSON = (badJSON) => badJSON

    // Replace ":" with "@colon@" if it's between double-quotes
    .replace(/:\s*"([^"]*)"/g, function(match, p1) {
        return ': "' + p1.replace(/:/g, '@colon@') + '"';
    })

    // Replace ":" with "@colon@" if it's between single-quotes
    .replace(/:\s*'([^']*)'/g, function(match, p1) {
        return ': "' + p1.replace(/:/g, '@colon@') + '"';
    })

    // Add double-quotes around any tokens before the remaining ":"
    .replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)(['"])?\s*:/g, '"$2": ')

    // Turn "@colon@" back into ":"
    .replace(/@colon@/g, ':')
;

const context = JSON.parse(fixBadJSON(contextBadJson));
const foo = stringToEval.replace(/(.*)(var foo = )(.*)(;)(.*)/mg, '$3');
console.log(context);
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: I understand your point, I'm assuming it's a fixed string. If not, I would still treat it with regex, for the safety of not using EVAL. Thanks for the feedback brô